# Keyboard shortcut to run a query from SQL view in Access 2010?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, microsoft-access

The title really covers it all - when manually typing a query in SQL View with Access 2010, is there a keyboard shortcut to run the query, like Ctrl + E in SQL Server Management Studio?

If not, it's almost as annoying as not being able to use Ctrl + A to select all text in the query window...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fastest way I found was using the keyboard navigation.

<kbd>F10</kbd>, <kbd>J</kbd>, <kbd>Q</kbd>, <kbd>X</kbd>

Comment: This was funny - I came here to answer my own question since I just now figured out how to do this, only to see it was answered today. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you're in design view then try Ctrl+ . (full stop).  To switch back use Ctrl+ , (comma).

From SQL view things work the other way round - Ctrl+ comma to switch to datasheet view and then Ctrl+ . to switch back to SQL view.

Think these are really meant as a way to toggle through all possible views.  Should also work when designing forms as well

Answer (score 0):

The shorcut key to run sql query in Access is <kbd>F10</kbd>, <kbd>R</kbd> then <kbd>G</kbd>. In this manner you can run your sql query in Access.